# Manta flow setting help needed

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

Help, my water sim is not working, i have the domain, flow and effector, but when i run the sim, the cup is not filling up fully, and is stacking up in the center and spilling up a column( see screen shot)
[[image: domain 1domain2]
[image: results]

When i first did this the cup filled up and, the fluid had pixelizartion. i tried to fix now i get this. what am i missing? please help as my aniamtion project needs this scene and i havw vlow sevral deadlines wrestling with this. any help will be greatly appreciated

[image: domain 3][image: flow][image: effector]

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing all the settings. Maybe you could upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question?